# Using Type Modifier (signed) Comparisons

Tags: c

This prints "signed comparison" https://onlinegdb.com/eA87wKQkU

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t A = -1, B = 1;

    if ((signed)A < (signed)B)
    {
        printf("signed comparison");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To ensure an overall signed comparison, looks like the `(signed)` type modifier must be applied to `A` and `B`.

Is this correct?

Also, I haven't seen any C code using `((signed)A < (signed)B)` and was wondering if it's valid C89/99?

Perhaps `((int64_t)A < (int64_t)B)` is a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: The cast `(signed)` converts the `uint64_t` to `int` so you may not be comparing what you think. The `signed` means `signed int` or `int`, like `unsigned` mean `unsigned int`.

Comment: `(signed)A` is almost certainly causing overflow, so the result is either undefined or implementation-defined, I'm not sure which.

Comment: Even `(int64_t)A` will cause overflow. The value of `A` is actually `UINT64_MAX`, which is larger than `INT64_MAX`.

Comment: Converting `-1 `to `uint64_t`is well defined. But converting `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` to `int` is not. Your last suggestion is the better approach, although it is hard to imagine what the use case is. The `-1` you assigned is no longer `-1`.

Comment: `if ((uint64_t)(A - INT64_MIN) < (uint64_t)(B - INT64_MIN))` will definitely work (as long as these optional types are supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes:

- if you only convert `A` or `B` as `(signed)`, which means `(signed int)`, the comparison will still be performed as `uint64_t` because the converted value will be converted to the larger type `uint64_t`. Converting both `A` and `B` is hence necessary.
- converting to `int64_t` is probably a better idea as this signed type is larger, but it should not matter in this particular example: converting `A`, whose value is `UINT64_MAX` to `int` or `int64_t` is implementation defined and may or may not produce `-1`. The C Standard allows for an implementation defined signal to be raised by this out of range conversion.
- on most current architectures, no signal will be raised and the conversion of `A` will indeed produce `-1` and the code will print `signed comparison`. Yet you should end the output with a newline for proper operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly unusual solution, irrelevant for all practical purposes, but it does have the one advantage of avoiding the following conversion rule from the C standard:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
> result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The idea of this solution is to invert the top bit of the unsigned type in the values being compared before the comparison.

Converting -1 to `uint64_t` produces the value `0xffffffffffffffff` in `A`.
Converting 1 to `uint64_t` produces the value `0x0000000000000001` in `B`.
So the comparison `A < B` is false.

Denoting `A` and `B` with the top bit inverted as `Ax` and `Bx` respectively, then `Ax` has the value `0x7fffffffffffffff` and `Bx` has the value `0x8000000000000001`. The comparison `Ax < Bx` is true.

One way to invert the top bit of a `uint64_t` value is to add or subtract `INT64_MIN` and convert the result back to `uint64_t`.  Converting `INT64_MIN` to `uint64_t` produces the value `0x8000000000000000` and adding or subtracting that to another `uint64_t` value will invert the top bit. This also works for any other exact-width unsigned type with the `64` changed to exact width in question.

So the following will do a "signed comparison" of the `uint64_t` values `A` and `B`:

```
if ((uint64_t)(A - INT64_MIN) < (uint64_t)(B - INT64_MIN))
    printf("A signed less than B\n");
```

Type-casting the adjusted values back to the unsigned integer type as shown above is only necessary for unsigned types whose values can all be represented by `int`. For example, it is necessary when `A` and `B` are of type `uint8_t`. `A` would have the value 255, `B` would have the value 1, `Ax` would have value 383 (for subtraction) or 127 (for addition), `Bx` would have the value 129 (for subtraction) or -127 (for addition), and `Ax < Bx` would be false.  The type-cast would convert `Ax` to 127 and `Bx` to 129 so the comparison `Ax < Bx` would be true.